# NextAuth signIn not triggering authorize method in my Credentials Provider

Tags: reactjs, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js project with NextAuth for authentication. I'm encountering an issue where the call to signIn in my Login component doesn't seem to trigger the authorize method in my Credentials Provider.

Here's an excerpt from my ...nextauth.js file:

```
CredentialsProvider({
  name: "credentials",
  credentials: {
    // ... (details omitted for brevity) ...
  },
  async authorize(credentials, req) {
    console.log("credentials", credentials);
    // ... (details omitted for brevity) ...
    const res = await fetch(`https://...`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: urlencoded,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    });

    const user = await res.json();

    if (res.ok && user) {
      return Promise.resolve(user);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }
})
```

And here's how I call signIn in my Login component:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  const result = await signIn('credentials', {
    username: emailRef.current?.value,
    password: passwordRef.current?.value,
  });

  console.log("result", result);
};
```

When I try to sign in, the console.log in the authorize method is never triggered, suggesting that signIn is not triggering authorize as expected. Also, signIn returns undefined.

I have checked that the provider name is correctly set as 'credentials' and that all necessary environment variables are properly set. There are no errors in the server logs.

Can anyone help me understand why signIn is not triggering authorize and how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. I am doing the login with the mongo db but signIn function returns the undefined

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my next version to 13.4.4 and next-auth to 4.22.1. This worked and I can see logs in authorize method.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, downgrading next and next-auth didn't work for me, @kishan-bhensadadiya did you have any luck?

Comment: Hi @SteveFord, I don't know why but upgrading node version to 20 worked for me by following this comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77141293/6570112